# Price formating for user but saving as INT

Tags: jquery, currency

I use wordpress and the plugin [JQ Price Format](http://jquerypriceformat.com/#examples) to format the numbers on a Input['preco-novo'] so the user types eq 3400000 and it shows 34.000,00. The thing is I need to save it as INT, and this plugin is editing the number and saving as float. Any ideas?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  $('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.' }); }); JQuery('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').focusout(function($) {     $('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    centsSeparator: '',
    thousandsSeparator: '' }); });
```

Comment: using string manipulation, replace the last comma or period with a period, then remove all non-numeric characters before that.

Comment: convert to string, and do what Kevin said, something like : `parseInt(('34.000,00').replace('.','').replace(',','.'),10);`

Comment: he said 'saving as a float' not 'saving as a string containing a number'

Comment: I need to save the number as INT but the jquery makes it a float. I tried a event to make it int when .focusout() like in my edit but does not work

Comment: but how do you want to save 34.044.35? like 3404435 or 34044?

Comment: i want to save it as 3404435

Comment: oh btw, i cant use parseint because it is saved by wordpress. It should convertd 23.000,00 to 2300000 with jquery on focusout

Comment: @user1576978 Then simply remove all non-numeric characters from the string and save it.

Comment: Kevin thats exacltly what i needed ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `Math.floor(your_float)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i had a problem with $ an jQuery because of wordpress compatibility error prevention.

The working code is like this:

```
jQuery('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').focus(function ($) {
    jQuery('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').priceFormat({
        prefix: '',
        centsSeparator: ',',
        thousandsSeparator: '.'
    });
});
jQuery('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').focusout(function ($) {
    jQuery('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').priceFormat({
        prefix: '',
        centsSeparator: '',
        thousandsSeparator: ''
    });
});
```

Thank you everyone who was kind enough to share your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you want to save the price as int, but you have few options here. Is not hard to make your owns `priceFormat` and `unFormat` function, avoid to use external jQuery plugins for small things like this one:

```
function priceFormat (num) {
    num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}

function unFormat(num){
    return parseInt((num).replace('.',''));
}
```

then you can do:

```
$('input[name="wpcf[preco-novo]"]').focus(function(){
    $(this).val(priceFormat($this.val());
}).focusout(function(){
    $(this).val(unFormat($this.val());
});
```